# Virtual Environment Transfer

Tags: django, heroku

Currently I have learnt Django and have made many projects. So, I wanted to deploy my projects on heroku but I have not made my projects in virtual Environment. So, they are not able to get deploy

So, my question is how to can I transfer my projects to virtual environment. Or I have to make all projects again in virtual Environment?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a django project you don't necessarily need a virtual environment, but it makes the preparation and deploy a bit easier.
I recommend that you first deploy a single, simple dummy django project to Heroku, so that you get an understanding of the project structure, the preconditions and the process. This is easier to understand than starting with a whole package of Django projects.

With this article you get a very understandable howto tutorial that explains exactly that in a very understandable way:

[Deploy Django 2 on Heroku](https://medium.com/@shuboy2014/deploy-django-2-on-heroku-224024f50d33)